# Is the principal branch of Lambert W function a single-valued function?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions

Is the principal branch of Lambert W function (i.e. $W_{0}(z)$) a single-valued function?

Comment: In what domain? In $\left| {\arg (z + {\rm e}^{ - 1} )} \right| < \pi$ it is.

Comment: It is as a bijective function $[-e^{-1},\infty) \to [-1,\infty)$